# Building a chain specification with --raw, gives me "wasm call error Other: Exported method GenesisBuilder_create_default_config is not found"

Tags: chainspec, build

I upgraded my parachain runtime version from 1.0.0 to 1.5.0, but when trying to build a chain spec with the `--raw` flag, it gives me the following error:
`Error: Service(Other("wasm call error Other: Exported method GenesisBuilder_create_default_config is not found"))`

Any ideas what might be causing it?
I'm using the version 1.73 of rustc and 1.71 (2023-05-22) of nightly.

```
active toolchain
----------------

1.73.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit]
I found the real reason, the `impl_runtime_apis!` macro in the runtime `lib.rs` file, have a new trait implementation exposing the missing method.

```rust
impl sp_genesis_builder::GenesisBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn create_default_config() -> Vec<u8> {
            create_default_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>()
        }

        fn build_config(config: Vec<u8>) -> sp_genesis_builder::Result {
            build_config::<RuntimeGenesisConfig>(config)
        }
    }
```

I'm using the cumulus parachain template as reference, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/polkadot-v1.5.0/cumulus/parachain-template

Comment: Perfect, thank you.